# Tengo un problemas al instalar el appcenter en elementary os 5.1 Hera

Tags: appcenter

Al intentar instalar el App Center en Elementary OS, tengo un error, el cual es:sudo apt install appcenter
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 appcenter : Depende: appstream (>= 0.12) pero no es instalable
             Depende: apt-config-icons pero no es instalable
             Depende: apt-config-icons-hidpi pero no es instalable
             Depende: apt-config-icons-large pero no es instalable
             Depende: apt-config-icons-large-hidpi pero no es instalable
             Depende: packagekit pero no es instalable
             Depende: libappstream4 (>= 0.11.0) pero no es instalable
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Si alguien tiene alguna solucion, porfavor.
y Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `sudo apt -f install` de esta forma se instalaran las dependencias faltantes automáticamente espero que te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

tengo el mismo problema para descargar desde la tienda de elementaryOS. Este es el error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  com.github.philip-scott.notes-up: Depende: libmarkdown2 (>= 2.0.6) but it is not installable
ya intenté todo:
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
reinicié el pc y aun nada. Agradezco mucho si alguien puede ayudarme.